# Filter and change data frame sum() and remove rows based on conditions

Tags: python, pandas, loops, conditional-statements

From data frame df need to receive data frame result, we need to iterate over df.id if there are more rows with same id and they are negative then we can sum() the quantity one by one, if the result is 0 or negative we remove this row from the data frame if the result is positive we keep it.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['1a','1a','b5','b5','1a','1a'],'date':['11-01-22', '12-01-22', '13-01-22', '21-01-22', '11-01-22', '18-01-22'],'quantity':[2,5,3,-1,-2,2]})

result = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['1a','b5','1a'],'date':['12-01-22', '13-01-22','18-01-22'],'quantity':[5,2,2]})
```

Comment: For B5 the result is 2 is that supposed to be 3?

Comment: why do the initial rows disappear? They are positive

Comment: It's still not clear what the logic is that you end up with those specific three rows... quantity per ID they're all positive... other rows are positive by themselves (4 of them)... ???

Comment: we need to iterate over df.id if there are more rows with same id and they are negative then we can sum()

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you want to aggregate per id/date and keep the positive quantities?

```
(df
 .groupby(['id', 'date'], as_index=False, sort=False).sum()
 .query('quantity > 0')
)
```

output:

```
   id      date  quantity
1  1a  12-01-22         5
2  b5  13-01-22         3
4  1a  18-01-22         2
```

Comment: Ahh... yeah... including the date matches the expected output... not mentioned in the post itself though... nicely worked out! Could always add a `sort=False` to the groupby and then it's even closer to the expected output :)

Comment: @Jon There's still a 2/3 discrepancy which I don't get

Comment: I'm guessing it's likely a typo from the OP